# Formatting maximum vertical spacing of underset and finding maximum vertical spacing in a document

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting, line-spacing, subscripts

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

 \newcommand{\smashundermin}[1]{\underset{\makebox[2pt]{}\smash{\mathclap{#1}}}{\:\operatorname{min}}\:}
 
\begin{document}
I don't like how underset/subscript messes with $v_{dir}$: \newline $\g_{dir}(s) = \smashundermin{u \in \textproc{PRED}_{dir}(s)}(v_{dir}(u) + c(u,s))$. Also, is there a way to calculate the largest vertical line space caused by underset and set the document to have uniform line spacing?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even if unnumbered, such a math text should be set in display  style (i.e., between `\[...\]`, rather than `$...$`)

Comment: also dir should be in \mathit (or \mathrm) not in the math italic font. This is why `\sum_0^n`  uses subscript setting in inline math and limits above and below in display math, The default definition of `\min` would do the same, you are forcing it to use underset which doesn't work inline.

Comment: Thanks guys,  ```\newcommand{\bettermin}[1]{\displaystyle \min_{\mathclap{#1}}}``` with ```\mathit``` and it looks a lot nicer. @Mico, is there any reason why I shouldn't use those?

Also, I'm currently using ```\onehalfspacing``` to make line spacing more uniform, but I was wondering if there was a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

One way to fix the vertical spacing issue is to modify the `\smashundermin` macro to bet rid of the `\smash` directive and add a `\vphantom` directive. Better still, use macros with voluminous underset material only in display math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}

\newcommand{\smashundermin}[1]{\underset{\makebox[2pt]{}\smash{\mathclap{#1}}}{\:\operatorname{min}}\:}
\newcommand{\undermin}[1]{\underset{\mathclap{#1}\vphantom{)^{)^a}}}{\min}}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{Before}

I don't like how underset/subscript messes with $v_{dir}$: 

$g_{dir}(s) = \smashundermin{u \in \textup{PRED}_{dir}(s)}(v_{dir}(u) + c(u,s))$. Also, is there a way to calculate the largest vertical line space caused by underset and set the document to have uniform line spacing?

\medskip
\textcolor{red}{After}

I don't like how underset/subscript messes with $v_\textup{dir}$: 

$g_{\textup{dir}}(s) = \undermin{u \in \textup{PRED}_{\textup{dir}}(s)}(v_{\textup{dir}}(u) + c(u,s))$. Also, is there a way to calculate the largest vertical line space caused by underset and set the document to have uniform line spacing?

\medskip
\textcolor{red}{Even better}

Underset/subscript no longer messes with $v_\textup{dir}$: 
\[
g_{\textup{dir}}(s) = \undermin{u \in \textup{PRED}_{\textup{dir}}(s)}(v_{\textup{dir}}(u) + c(u,s)) 
\]
Also, is there a way to calculate the largest vertical line space caused by underset and set the document to have uniform line spacing?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the different approaches, much appreciated!